# Windows 7 freeze when Debugging in VS 2013

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, windows-7, freeze

I have following problem: Sometimes, when I debug a C++ project in VS 2013, my complete Windows freezes! This means:

- GUI is updated (i.e. previous opened Task Manager is updating values)
- Can not close VisualStudio
- Can not close any program (i.e. firefox, the program which is been debugged, outlook, ...)
- killing any process via Task Manager not working
- Klicking Windows start button not working
- Hitting Strg+Alt+Del not working
- The only thing I can do is press and holding the I/O Hardware button at my Laptop

The system is a Windows 7 Enterprise x64 with SSD, 16GB RAM and i7 CPU. Symantec Endpoint Protection is installed from our IT. Some of my collegues have the same problem. We think, that this problem only occures if mixed-Debugging with Managed-Code, Unmanged-Code and COM in code is used.

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: A question like this needs to document the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: Have you looked at the event log for additional information?

Comment: Hi, the Eventlog does not show any errors for this time.